# CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Soap' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters'

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, .net-4.5

I am using .NET 4.5 Visual Studio 2012 web application . It gives me runtime error as

> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Soap' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters'

But I added the reference already to `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;`

And also in the Class file as;

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
```

Comment: That isn't a runtime error - that's a compilation error. Are you sure you've added a reference to the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll` assembly in your project? Note that that's *very* different from the `using` directive you've shown, which is to do with namespaces...

Comment: When i am building it shows me build succeeded . I tried removing that reference and added again . no luck

Comment: Are you sure it's a web application rather than a web *site* project? Basically, and error of CS0234 is a C# compilation error... What kind of file is it that's causing the problem? (Page codebehind, or something else?)

Comment: Yes . Thanks for that . Mine is website project . I closed it and opened as a web site its fired on compile time and i added that . Now it solved .

Answer (score 1):

A reference needs to be added from the framework. Just check and add this:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap
```

Answer (score 0):

go to Solution Explorer, Right click on Reference, Then select 1st option i.e. Add Reference.
select assemblies and search SOAP in search bar.
select library and press ok.
error will get solved